# How to properly add new lines in algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e

I am trying to write algoritm in a way that separate line in the code should be separate line after compiling latex I use \ symbol to achieve this but for some reason it do not work. I work and compile latex using overleaf.

packages

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
```

code

```
\begin{algorithm}[H] \label{algo:2}
\SetAlgoLined 
\DontPrintSemicolon 
\KwData{goldGPU}   \label{alg:alg2Dat1}  \ 
\KwData{segmGPU} \
\KwData{numberToLookFor}   \label{alg:alg2Dat3}  \

boolGold = goldGPU[x,y,z]==numberToLookFor \label{alg:alg2A1} \
boolSegm = segmGPU[x,y,z]==numberToLookFor \

if(boolGold)\label{alg:alg2A2} \
    addSumXYZGold() \
end if \
if(boolSegm) \
    addSumXYZSegm() \
end if \

syncGrid()\label{alg:alg2A3} \

if(boolGold)\label{alg:alg2A4} \
    getVariancesAndCovGold() \
end if \
if(boolSegm) \
    getVariancesAndCovSegm() \
end if \

syncGrid() \ 
a = sqrt(varianceX) \label{alg:alg2A5} \
b = (covarianceXY)/a \
c = (covarianceXZ)/a \
e = sqrt(varianceY - b^2) \
d = (covarianceYZ -(c * b))/e \

f= (meanXgold -meanXsegm)   /a  \label{alg:alg2A6} \
g = ( meanYgold -meanYsegm)  -b*f)/e\
h= ( meanZgold -meanZsegm  )  -g*d-f* c)/sqrt(varianceZ - c^2 -d^2)\
result = sqrt(f^2+g^2+h^2)\

return result

\label{alg:a2}\
\caption{Calculating Mahalanobis distance}
\end{algorithm}
```

display
[image]

so question is how to separate lines for example lines begining from a=; b= ... should be in new lines and they are not what am I doing wrong?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: thank you for welcomming :)

Comment: @JakubMitura: I think you're confusing pseudo-code for actual code. You present the latter, which is often set as a listing (using the [`listings` package](//ctan.org/pkg/listings)). Here's an example of [your code](https://pastebin.com/raw/6VLUaAbZ) ([output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pci3e.png)). Pseudo-code is set using an appropriate algorithm package (like [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) or [`algorithms`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) or [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)). You'll typically have to rewrite your regular code into pseudo-code as it stands.

Comment: but I am using algorithm2e :)

Comment: @JakubMitura: Then I'd suggest rewriting your actual code into pseudo-code, since that's what [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) is used for.